# Display a file hierarchically under another file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

In Visual Studio, I'd like to show a hierarchical relationship between certain files.

A typical ASP.NET WebForms application provides an example of what I want. 
Say that I have a file named `Page.aspx`. Files named `Page.aspx.cs` and `Page.aspx.designer.cs` would typically appear hierarchically below `Page.aspx` in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want File A to appear hierarchically under File B in Solution Explorer, do the following:

Open your project file, go to the `<Content Include>` (or `<None Include>`, or what have you) node for File A and add a `<DependentUpon>File B</DependentUpon>` child to it. The result should look similar to this:

```xml
<Content Include="File A">
  <DependentUpon>File B</DependentUpon>
</Content>`
```

Comment: This extensions makes it a little easier : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ebde8fb-26d8-4374-a0eb-1e4e2665070c